# ID1073 WIF Nested Applications

Tags: .net, iis-7.5, wif, adfs

I have issue with WIF connecting to AD FS. Our sites are set up as follows

1. Production Link - `https://app.domain.com/`
2. Test Link -  `https://app.domain.com/TestSite`

The test site is used for testing changes before qualifying to production. However when we try to authenticate via AD FS, we get the following error. 
`Key not valid for use in specified state.`

This issue was not happening when the sites were set up like the following.

1. Production Link - `https://dev.domain.com/ProdSite`
2. Test Link -   `https://dev.domain.com/TestSite`

I have searched through all of stack overflow and was not able to find a solution for WIF error ID1073.

IIS App Pool Settings are as follows

```
LoadUser Profile: Yes
Identity: ApplicationPoolIdentity
.NET Framework Version - 2.0
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with Relying Party configuration. The client was pointing both endpoint URLs to the base domain rather than the virtual directory (for the test site).

Thanks,
Kal